# VB & Chinese string

Tags: unicode, vb6, utf-16

I am trying to capture a Chinese text from a website using VB6

simple code used to do this as below, working good with the English sites

```
    Private Function RequestText(sURL, Optional sMethod = "POST")
    'You may have caching issues using GET
    Dim XMLHTTP
    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    sMethod = UCase(sMethod)
    XMLHTTP.Open sMethod, sURL, False
    XMLHTTP.send (Null) '"x=x"

    RequestText = XMLHTTP.responseText
    Set XMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function

Private Sub cmdText_Click()
    Dim html as string
    html = RequestText("http://url")
    Clipboard.Clear
    Clipboard.SetText html
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

When trying to paste the text to word, notepad or db, the Chinese characters appears as ???? 
Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 is ANSI when calling API calls as WIN95 didn't support unicode. In COM and internally it's Unicode. Therefore any API call, as the clipboard requires, your TEXT will be converted to ANSI. Therefore don't use TEXT. XMLHTTP has several formats to choose from.

Internet Explorer can access the clipboard. Use it to do it.

This sample code reads the clipboard. NB you have to navigate to ANY local file to avoid security prompts.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Sub Clip
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
    ie.Visible = 0
    ie.Navigate2 FilterPath & "Filter.html"
    Do 
        wscript.sleep 100
    Loop until ie.document.readystate = "complete"  
    txt=ie.document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
    ie.quit
    If IsNull(txt) = true then 
        outp.writeline "No text on clipboard"
    else
        outp.writeline txt
    End If
End Sub
```